# How to rename a directory in Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, rename

May I know how how to rename a directory? because I have a directory which contains more files inside.

Thank You.

Comment: By file-manager? Terminal? Magic?(Magic takes for **ever**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try command `mv <Old_directory_Name> <New_Directory_Name>`

e.g.: `mv test_Old test_New`

Hope you only want to change the directory name.